# How to use Copay with Trezor?

Tags: trezor, copay

I have a trezor. Now I want to use it with Copay, how should I?
I would like to think the seed should stay in Trezor so I should not key in anything to Copay. But when I tried with the recent Copay version 3.7.0 it doesn't lead me anywhere.

How can I use Copay with trezor, specifically the later 3.7.0 version of Copay? (My trezor also setup today with its latest firmware).

Answer (score 1):

Last time I check, Copay has not supported trezor on mobile devices yet. You can only use trezor with Copay on desktop. Just create new wallet with hardware wallet type.